# MTLRenderPipelineAttachmentDescriptor swift linker error

Tags: swift, ios8, metal

I have linker error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>   _OBJC_CLASS_$_MTLRenderPipelineAttachmentDescriptorArray

with following code

```
var pipelineStateDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
pipelineStateDescriptor.label = "Test1"
pipelineStateDescriptor.sampleCount = 1
pipelineStateDescriptor.vertexFunction = vertexFunction
pipelineStateDescriptor.fragmentFunction = fragmentFunction

var colorDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineAttachmentDescriptor()
colorDescriptor.pixelFormat = .FormatBGRA8Unorm

pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0] = colorDescriptor
```

Is any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

***Update:
This bug is no more actual in ios8 beta 3.***

In your project build settings set "Optimization level" to "**-Ofast**", like this

[image]

Here is short info on compiler optimization flags

[image]

It seems to be a bug of beta sdk. I made a project in which I try to use Metal with Swift, go check it out https://github.com/haawa799/METAL_Playground.

Hope it will help.